# Selenium find_element that is unavailable / hidden

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, element

I'm using Python's selenium to automate my university course registration but there are elements in a page that is part of the registration process and that page is currently unavailable for me ( I get a time ticket error ) so I cant copy the elements' xpaths and paste it into the find_element method, I have to wait for the registration to open and that part/page of the website to becomes available.

My questions is: Can I open this missing page from the page source or any other way before having direct access to it?

Comment: Tip:  Each word you write asking about programming without including code should make you feel increasing uneasy.

Comment: That depends entirely on the implementation of your university's site. But a properly made course registration site probably wouldn't leak such details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with selenium, you can download the complete source code when available and use that to identify the element by accessing it locally.

But it's not a good idea to do that because some parts of the websites might rely on API calls. As a result you might not get the whole picture.

My suggestion is to grab the code when the website is live